# Boost Iostreams vs Boost Interprocess for mapping a file

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapped-files, boost-interprocess, boost-iostreams

I see there are two ways to memory-map a file in Boost:

1. boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source
2. boost::interprocess::mapped_region

I understand the latter is intended towards sharing a memory-mapped file across multiple processes.

Does this mean `boost::interprocess::mapped_region` contains additional overhead to facilitate the ability to share across processes?

If someone didn't want to share a mapped file amongst processes, they would get better performance using `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source`?